# Click function not working as expected. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using tkinter to make a gui in python. I made a button that is supposed to change the text of the label when clicked.

I've been trying to master tkinter guis for some time now, but I cannot fix this problem and I don't know why.

```
Lbl = Label(Wndw, text = "click that")
Lbl.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

Btn = Button(Wndw, text = ":]")
Btn.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

def Clicked():
    Lbl.configure(text = "Yay")
```

Of course, tkinter doesn't usually give error messages for things like this, so I don't know what the problem is. Again, the button is expected to change the text of the label when clicked, however, it has no effect.

Comment: Your button doesn’t have a command set.

Comment: Read [The Tkinter Button Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)